# capacity of the capacitor in two states

Tags: capacitance

what is the difference between the capacity of the capacitor when we ignore the effect of the sides and in reality?(with regarding side effcts)
this question is from"fundamental of physics by 'rex neleson'".
I couldn't solve it because I knew just guass's law for calculating the capacity but with regarding side effects,it doesn't work...
thank you

Comment: The thing you mean by "side effect",  is actually called fringing of electric field. This causes additional electric field around the sides other than that existing in between the capacitor. This causes the capacitance value to increase than as we expected from the calculation.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Is it obvious that the capacitance should increase?

Comment: Another way of what @Unnikrishnan and sammy said is that the electromagnetic field has an energy density, so if you have additional volume, then there is more energy in total. The additional volume in case of a plate capacitor is not just around the sides of the plates, by the way, it's all around the device. If you need a shielded capacitor, you have to go with something like a spherical capacitor design. There the field is completely encased in a finite volume. A little more practical is a Leyden jar kind of cylindrical design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that the book question is asking for a qualitative answer, as provided by @Unnikrishnan in his comment, rather than a formula.  The capacitance increases because the fringing fields effectively increase the area of the plates.  You can see this in diagrams which show the field lines extending onto the back of the capacitor plates.  These fields are present also when the gap between the plates is much smaller than their width or diameter, but their effect on capacitance is much less significant.

A formula for a circular parallel plate capacitor is given in the first link below.  Details of an experiment to verify the formula are included.  A formula for a capacitor with square plates is much more difficult to obtain because of the lack of circular symmetry.

The second link discusses various approximate formulae for the circular capacitor.

http://www.santarosa.edu/~yataiiya/UNDER_GRAD_RESEARCH/Fringe%20Field%20of%20Parallel%20Plate%20Capacitor.pdf
http://meeng.technion.ac.il/Research/TReports/2004/ETR-2004-02.pdf